# Good HD Health Checkers/Programs

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, diagnostic

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When to stop using a HDD? What rules/software apply?](https://superuser.com/questions/157266/when-to-stop-using-a-hdd-what-rules-software-apply)
>   [How to check the health of a hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/171195/how-to-check-the-health-of-a-hard-drive)

Hello guys,

Can anyone recomend me good HD diagnostic tools? Light weigth and free?

Comment: Look at http://superuser.com/questions/171195/how-to-check-the-health-of-a-hard-drive and http://superuser.com/questions/157266/when-to-stop-using-a-hdd-what-rules-software-apply

Answer (score 1):

Use the manufacturer's diagnostic tools.

You can either get them from the manufacturer's website (though you may need to jump through a few hoops to locate them), or download the Ultimate Boot CD, which has them included.

http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/

Comment: In deed, almost all manufacturers have their own HDD diag tool on their website.

Answer (score 1):

While pricey [spinrite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) is the best diagnostic and recovery tool I have ever used for a hard drive.