# Why sometimes Windows 7 cannot see IDE disk?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata, pata

We have two internal hard drives; one SATA and one IDE. Windows 7 (x86) sees both of them. But sometimes when we boot the computer IDE drive fails. After restart everything behave normal. Every 1 boot in 10 this happens.

Anyone experienced something like this? Is there any problem using SATA and IDE drives together?

Comment: Replace the IDE cable with a new 80 pin cable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem using IDE ans SATA drives together. My guess is that you are having some sort of hardware problem.  It can be something so easy as a loose cable or it might be that your IDE drive is failing.

I would start with [checking the health of my HDD](https://superuser.com/questions/171195/how-to-check-the-health-of-a-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

Check in Disk Manager to see if these hard drive are listed as basic or dynamic if the above hardware (new 80pin cable) doesnt help.