# Harddisk not mounting: not recognized under Devices - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 desktop computer.

According to my code I mounted my harddrive and then copy a file in it. I also use 2 USB for this copy operation.

Today I got into trouble. Firstly one of my USB's partition table is corrupted. For solving this I formatted my USB Drive. Then it looks OK. But after rebooting, my computer didn't recognize my harddisk under Devices. Although it looks in the output of fdisk -l and lsscsi when I attemped to mount it I'm getting an error.

- `fdisk -l` output:

  ```
  Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
  255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
  Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disk identifier: 0x0c1190ed

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sdb1   *          63   488392064   244196001    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  ```
- `lsscsi` output:

  [1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      KINGSTON SNV425S D100  /dev/sda
  [4:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD2500JD-00G 02.0  /dev/sdb
- sudo lsblk -f output:

  NAME   FSTYPE                     LABEL MOUNTPOINT
  sda
  ├─sda1 ext4                             /
  ├─sda2
  └─sda5 swap                             [SWAP]
  sdb    silicon_medley_raid_member
  └─sdb1
- `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/Disk1` output:

  mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Then I run this command:

- `sudo mount -t silicon_medley_raid_member /dev/sdb1 /media/Disk1`
  output:

  mount: unknown filesystem type 'silicon_medley_raid_member'

Then tried this way:

- `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media/Disk1` output:

  ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
  Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x0)
  Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
  Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
  NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
  SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
  then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
  important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
  it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
  /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
  for more details.

My harddisk didn't exist in `blkid` output also.

I can not figure out what the problem is, I would appreciate if someone gives any suggestion.

Comment: It seems unlikely that you would want to mount an external USB disc as a RAID member, so maybe it needs re-formatting. Try using the `Disks` utility: you can examine, format and mount from this using a simple graphical interface. If `Disks` is insufficient, try `GParted`.

Comment: Note the following from your mount attempt: `Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error`. That suggests failing (or failed) hardware. You might try [running a SMART test](http://superuser.com/questions/171195/how-to-check-the-health-of-a-hard-drive) on the disk. If you think it's OK, consider further output you've reported: `In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very important!` NTFS problems *cannot* be fixed in Linux; they *must* be fixed from Windows! It could also be a cabling problem.

Comment: Thank you both guys, after formatting the disk, everything is OK now.