# Microsoft reserved partition (Unable to detect file system!) + CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED error

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, gparted

EDIT : I finally did this actually it is a little long story.  I install windows 8 and i had same issues after one rebooting but after another reboot it can boot and i install bitdefender there is no problem now with windows but this time i couldnt open ElementaryOS :D:D i just solve this issue now just open command line and write : `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`  and it install something and DİSABLE secure boot . So i just write this on my elementaryOS  i hope it can be usefull for everyone :)

[Befor windows start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWqRr.jpg)

[it try to repair but cant do anything when i try to format i have same issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtdnv.jpg)

Hello guys i just install windows 10 after this i just install Elementary OS as a second system. And today when i try to open windows i have CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED error and when i open with elementart os and look gparted it says :

Name : Microsoft Reserved Partition
File System : Unknown
Size : 16.00 Mib
Flags: msftres 
Status : Not mounted

Warning : 
Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:
- The file system is damaged
- The file system is unknown to GParted
- There is no file system available (unformatted)
- The device entry /dev/sda3 is missing.

i search about it but i cant find any solution. Thanks for any help :)

Edit : i install Windows 10 and same day Elementary OS but after that i could use windows bootloader too. İ mean i could use both system. One night i was close computer and morning i cant open Windows

```
Progress is like this: 
1. Push the Open button
2. When pc try to open i just have blue screen - Process died error-
3. Pc try to restart itself and i see a text "Try to repairing" 
4. It said that it cant be repaired and pc close.
"Sure i will add a video or photos"
```

And that is 2. answer :

```
Model: ATA ST1000LM014-SSHD (scsi)

Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B

Partition Table: gpt

Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  473MB   472MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      473MB   578MB   105MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      578MB   595MB   16.8MB                  Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      595MB   822GB   821GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      822GB   983GB   161GB   ext4
 6      983GB   1000GB  17.1GB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: Actually i didnt do anything because i cant find any solution about it

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Reserved partition is normally empty -- it doesn't even contain a filesystem. Thus, an inability of GParted to detect a filesystem on it is normal. That said, it's unclear precisely what is producing those messages, so it could be something else is going on, like failing disk hardware. Posting a clearer description of what you do to get those messages from GParted (perhaps including screen shots) might be worthwhile. You might also try [collecting SMART data](https://superuser.com/questions/171195/how-to-check-the-health-of-a-hard-drive) on the disk to check its health, in case the disk is failing.

You're more likely to get results by focusing on the Windows boot failure, though. I'm not a Windows expert, so I likely won't be able to help much, but you should answer some additional questions to provide those who might be able to help with more information:

- Were you ever able to boot Windows after installing Elementary OS? (If not, then something about the Elementary OS installation may have damaged Windows. If you could boot to Windows, even once, after installing Elementary OS, then it's more likely to be a Windows-centric failure.)
- What does your partition table look like? The output of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` or `sudo parted /dev/sda print` in Elementary OS should be informative (although Windows folks might prefer the output of Windows tools -- but as you can't boot Windows, that will be harder to obtain).
- What is the *exact* and *complete* sequence of events from power on to failure? Posting a video may be helpful, or at least a sequence of screen shots.

One other possibility occurs to me: If you accidentally created a mixed-mode installation (Windows in EFI mode and Linux in BIOS mode, or vice-versa), this might explain your problem. To help diagnose this possibility, please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here.

Comment: The BootInfo Summary from Boot Repair (see the link in my answer) will help narrow the range of possible problem causes.

Comment: i think it should give me an url but it give me this A new file (~/Boot-Info_2017-05-07__22h22.txt) will open in your text viewer.


If you are experiencing boot issues, indicate the content of this file to people who help you. For example on forums or via email.

Comment: Then try posting that file to [a pastebin site.](https://paste2.org/)

Comment: Unfortunatell, it save that file on root folder and i cant access

Comment: i just add some pictures but i cant add more because i dont have reputation